# Eclipse dc error

Tags: java, eclipse, printing

I'm trying to compile the following code to Eclipse Luna but I'm getting only red errors 
 
When I compile it it show a red error and does nothing,
Example dc: 2014/10/23 20:05:34.574: setAttribute(PAPER=[(0, 0, 0, 0, 612, 792)]) 
Any help?

Below is the code:

```
import com.activetree.common.print.SilentPrint;
import com.activetree.pdfprint.SilentPrintPdf;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

/**
 * This is yet another example demonstrating how to set the silent print
 * parameters for printing of your PDF documents. It shows how
 * to set custom paper size and few other parameters. See other examples
 * in the downloaded archive. 
 */
public class SilentPrintPdfPrintAttrs {
  public static final String usage = "C:\\Users\\txt.pdf";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(usage);


    SilentPrint silentPrint = new SilentPrintPdf();

    //default media size
    String paperSize = "(0, 0, 0, 0, 612, 792)";
    silentPrint.setAttribute(SilentPrint.PAPER, paperSize);

   }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: dc: 2014/10/23 20:05:34.574: setAttribute(PAPER=[(0, 0, 0, 0, 612, 792)])  is in red and the program doesn'T start printing

Thats the problem that I don't know what error it is!
@RealSkeptic

Comment: Do you see a red circle with an X to the left of the line? Or perhaps a light bulb with a small X? The error message is in there. You should read the error message and try to fix it.

Comment: No there are no error on the program thats the problem!

Comment: Maybe if you posted a screen shot it would make things clearer.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kjfTu.png

Can't upload images because of my reputation!

Comment: Well, the command setAttribute probably prints that line to System.err (not System.out), which is why it's in red. Since setAttribute is the last command in your program, the program ends.